# iOS debugging is terminated directly after it started (Xamarin.Forms / VS for Mac)

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

I'm currently trying to debug an iOS application (created with Xamarin.Forms) with VS for Mac (also tested through VS2019 Enterprise on Windows). Unfortunately, the debugging process is not started successfully. It stops without any exception or error report (except "Application 'com.XYZ.MyApp' terminated." which is not helpful at all). This happens with the simulator and the device debugging.

When debugging it shows the launch screen and from time to time the following page. Then the debugging crashes without any report. This may be caused by an asyncronous process. However, there is no information in the log files.

The same app can be successfully debugged with the andriod simulator. Moreover, a generally similiar application can be debugged under iOS.

Is there any possibility to get a more detailed error report that shows why the debugger is closing?

Edit: I just created a TestFlight version which works pretty stable and pretty well... So I have no clue anymore why the debugging is not working... Is it maybe because I had Xcode 11 beta installed for a short time to test iOS 13 on my device with my apps? I uninstalled Xcode 11 after the iOS update but is there a chance that this causes problems with the Xcode 10 installation?

Comment: Are you sure your provisioning profile is and certificates are present on the mac and you have selected the correct one?

Comment: @G.hakim yes because I can upload test flight versions and the debugging is trying to start. Without the profile it won’t even Upload to the device and there should be no issue with the Simulator.

Comment: Okay so you are able to work with release the actual debug does not work is it?

Comment: @G.hakim as it says in the text already, yes. The debugging starts (splash screen) and then gets interrupted without any message. So I'm sure the profiles are correct (otherwise it won't be able to upload to the device and the simulator should not be affected by it). After more research, I found out that there is a background thread canceled each time before the debugging gets interrupted but I have no idea how I can find which one. Because this did not happen on Android, I think it must be a Apple feature (Spotlight indexing, watchOS, Today Widget) that causes this issue.

Comment: Have you cleaned all the project cache from the Mac machine? Try cleaning the `~/Library/caches/xamarin/mtbs/builds` directory and then restart VS windows and try clean build deploy.

Comment: @G.hakim I normally use VS for Mac to develop iOS. The VS 2019 on Windows was just used for testing purposes (with the same result). And yes, I cleared the whole cache. This issue happens btw. since debug try #1 on this project and at that point it was a plain copy of a project that works for debugging. The only difference there was another name, other images and different data db3 file. But that was not the question. The question is how can I get more details out of VS why the debugging is interrupted. I mean the IDE should know this, right? And I'm sure I'm able to fix it with a IDE hint...

Comment: Maybe you should check for the iOS device logs in that case

Comment: Are you using any Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging nuGet packages? I had a very similar problem with my app, and downgrading from the most recent version of those packages fixed my issue.